# How to increase TextField`s Height in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, textfield, kivymd

I Want to Create TextEditor in kivymd and i stucked at increasing height of a TextField

How Can I add to the TextField`s Height?

and this is the textfield` code:

I tried size_hint, theme_height, height,
whatever?

and i tried to
`size: root.width,root.height`

Comment: KivyMD does a lot of things for you, but that often means that you are stuck with what they decide to do for you. The `MDTextField` sets its own height to the minimum height that will contain the text. If you want to actually set the height, try using the `TextInput` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDTextField's height is defined by the size of the text font within, so you could:

- set font_size in MDTextField
- use TextInput instead (which MDTextField inherits from)

Comment: ty. yea i used TextInput